# Excel - VBA - Compile error: Method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I create a form dynamically and fill it with check boxes generated based on all column names of the Excel sheet it is launched from.
I add also a command button.
Here is the code put directly on the form:

```
Option Explicit

Dim cmdArray() As New Class1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim myButton As Control
    
    lastCol = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Me.Height = 500
    Me.Width = 600
    
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", i)
        chkBox.Caption = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value
    '        chkBox.Name = i
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
            chkBox.Left = 5
            chkBox.Top = 5 + (i - 1) * 10
            chkBox.Width = 200
        Else
            chkBox.Left = 250
            chkBox.Top = 5 + (i - 2) * 10
            chkBox.Width = 200
        End If
    Next i
    
    i = 1
    Set myButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "MyButton", False)
        With myButton
            .Left = 500
            .Top = chkBox.Top - 50
            .Width = 50
            .Caption = "Hide"
            .Visible = True
        End With
        
        ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To i)
        Set cmdArray(i).CmdEvents = myButton
    
        Set myButton = Nothing
        
    Me.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
    Me.ScrollHeight = chkBox.Top + 20
End Sub
```

The form is generated without issue: all check-boxes and the command button are set correctly.

I am then supposed to select which columns I want to hide from my Excel sheet, and therefore I tick the relevant checkbox. So far so good. Here is the code set is a Class :

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim cbx As MSForms.Control
Dim colNum As Integer

    i = 0
    
    For Each cbx In Me.UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(cbx) = "CheckBox" Then
            If cbx.Value = True Then
                colNum = cbx.Name - i
                Worksheets(1).Columns(colNum).EntireColumn.Delete
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

When I click the button, it is supposed to trigger the hiding of the columns in the Excel sheet, however, I got the following error:

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

This error is reported in the code in the Class module, highlighting the term .UserForm1 and if I remove this **.UserForm1**, then still the same error highlighting the **.Controls**.

I am not a great specialist of VBA, I manage usually to create simple codes and reusing samples I can find here and there, but this time, I run out of idea (and understanding), so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In your class code you have Me.Userform1.controls.  This is incorrect because Me refers to the instance of the class, which according to your code doesn't have a public method or field called UserForms1.  Therefore remove the 'Me' in this line of code and then, if UserForms1 is a publicly available form the error should go away.

Comment: That was finally so easy. Many thanks @freeflow